# Seeking min value - "TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable"

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, tabulate

Couldn't find an answer in previous questions on the subject.

I'm trying to get the minimum value in a column of data, using the following code:

```
import pandas as pd import matplotlib.pyplot as plt import numpy as np

from tabulate import tabulate as tb from pandas.plotting import scatter_matrix

.......

table = ("Sepal Area (cm^2)", iris_ds.loc[:,"Sepal_area_(cm^2)"].min())
print(tb(table, headers = ["Field", "Min"]))
```

However, when I run the code, I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "Iris_Data_set1.py", line
>   148, in 
>       print(tb(table, headers = ["Field", "Min"]))
>   File "C:...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tabulate.py", line 1262, in
>   tabulate
>       tabular_data, headers, showindex=showindex)
>   File "C:...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tabulate.py", line 947, in
>   _normalize_tabular_data
>       rows = list(map(list,rows)) TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable

I've checked the data types, and

> Sepal_area_(cm^2)    float64

Any ideas on how to fix this

Comment: you want to print a table where col1 contains the name of the column and col2 the min of all the column is that right ? you table will contain only one row

Comment: Yes, but eventuality it will have multiple rows and columns